# Как удалить три или более подряд идущих элемента из массива?

Tags: c++

Дан массив, состоящий из N элементов. Например, дана последовательность `arr[N] = {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8}`

Требуется удалить 3 или более подряд идущих элемента.

На выходе должно получиться `8 8`.

Comment: А как Вы бы это на бумажке решали?

Answer (score 0):

**способ 1 (с извратами):**

1.1. найти последовательность повторяющихся чисел (начало и размер)

1.2. если размер больше 3, то в новый массив копировать только 3 числа иначе всю последовательность

1.3. заменить старый массив новым

последовательность одинаковых чисел найти просто:

2.1. пройти в цикле от первого до последнего (предпоследнего) элемента

2.2. если текущий элемент равен следующему - увеличить длительность текущей последовательности

2.3. иначе считать, что последовательность закончилась и см. п.1.1

**способ 2 (без извратов)**

1. пройтись по всем элементам исходного массива
2. если текущий элемент равен предыдущему (или текущий элемент первый), увеличить счетчик одинаковых элементов
3. если счетчик одинаковых элементов не больше 3, то записать элемент в новый массив
4. если счетчик одинаковых элементов больше 3, то ничего не делать
5. если текущий элемент не равен предыдущему - сбросить счетчик до 1 и дальше см. п.3

Comment: Выводится `7 7 5 5 4 4 8 8`
Вот код: https://pastebin.com/zBCPu5NU

Comment: ну вроде как раз то что требуется

Comment: должно, чтобы  вывелось `8 8`

Comment: а... - а я подумал что надо обрезать до 3 если элементов больше

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы выводилось `8 8` ?

Comment: @lim, 2 варианта сразу в голову приходит - 1) накапливать во временный массив и если его размер меньше 3, то переписывать в результирующий массив 2) все писать сразу в результирующий массив, но если длина последовательности больше 3, то отрезать у результирующего массива кол-во элементов равное размеру последовательности (делать срезы) - так что выбирайте что вам больше нравится